# Track daily users signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I want to output users that signed in 2 hours ago with the hope I will call it on the front end, and I have a database attribute (`created_at`)that keeps track of the time you sign in.

What I did was to define a scope to handle that which got nothing from. Here is my code below:

```
class SignupHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :one_hour_ago, -> { where 'created_at > ?', Time.now - 2.hours.ago  }
end
```

How do I go about showing users that logged in 2 hours ago?

Comment: Sign-up or sign-in?

Comment: Dont mind the class actually, but I will deal with the naming. The class records active datetime when you sign in.

Comment: The code looks fine, maybe you have some issues with timezones? If your DB and machine timezones are different you may have troubles with such query.

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi: "The class records active datetime when you sign in"  - and it records a user id? If so, it should "just work".

Comment: So why am I not just getting anything? Or how do I test this scope from Console?

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi you should be able to see the resulting SQL queries in the log (when you try this in a console, for example). You can then check that your database does indeed contain data matching this query.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct to understand that you are trying to find all the records that were created within the last two hours? Then, you can just test against `2.hours.ago` without any subtraction operator:

```
scope :two_hours_ago, -> { where 'created_at > ?', 2.hours.ago  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're calling `.ago`. 
You should be able to accomplish what you need by calling:

```
scope :one_hour_ago, -> { where 'created_at > ?', Time.zone.now - 2.hours }
```

Comment: "this will find users who signed _up_ less than two hours ago" - note that the scope is not on the user model